# How to store large text on Azure platform (SQL database, Table storage, Blobs...)

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to build a chat application. I also need to store all chat transcripts into some storage - SQL database, Table storage or other Azure mechanism.
It should store about 50 Mega of characters per day. Each bulk of text should be attach to a specific customer.

My question:

What is the best way to store such amount of text in Azure?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your only concern at the moment being the storage of chat data?

Comment: This is an opinion-solicitation question; there's no *best way* - it's going to be dependent on your app and its query requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would store them in Azure Tables, using conversationId as the partition key, and messageID as the rowKey. That way, you can easilly aggregate your statistics based on those two, and quickly retrieve conversations.

Comment: Pedro --> I would not outrightly recommend Table Storage. Table Storage is good for many things but is not suitable for storing large amount of data in a single entity. Normally for data storage, Blob Storage is recommended however Table Storage is good place to store the data cheaply if the size of 1 unit of data  is small and there's a querying requirement.

Comment: I'm not talking about storing the entire 50MB into one row/key combination. Store each line in the conversation and you effectively have a shallow key/value database that you can query ultra-fast based on conversationID, messageId and timestamp. Beats blobs by a mile. And remember, Table Storage = Blob storage in terms of capacity.

Comment: I agree however OP has not asked for any querying recommendation. OP has asked only for storing data. I believe OP needs to provide more details into the question.

Comment: "I would store them in ..." - purely opinion. And there's no basis for choosing table storage over any other storage mechanism, in the context of the (opinion-soliciting) question.

Comment: Everything is an opinion David. There are always great arguments to do something. "Best practices" do not exist, only "Good practices". The reasoning behind table storage is that it is blazingly fast when partitioned smart, and it is also hyper cost effective. Instead of voting me down, you should rather provide an alternative.